# Generate BBL file and no other intermediate files?

Tags: bibtex, auxiliary-files, texpad, bbl

I use Texpad, and typeset with intermediate files hidden. Since I use BibTeX for references, I periodically need to access the BBL file, for example to create a file containing the references that's separate from the main document.

The typical way I do this is quite annoying: I elect to show the intermediate files, then typeset again, then copy the contents of the BBL file, then delete all the intermediate files again.

My question is whether there is an easier way to do this? For example, is it possible from the terminal to generate *just* the BBL file, without any of the other intermediate files?

Comment: No.  Short answer.

Comment: If I understand https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/hide-intermediate-files correctly, you could also simply make the hidden folder `.texpadtmp` visible (I don't own a Mac so I wouldn't know how to do that) and get the `.bbl` from there. I think that usually these 'hide temporary files' options cause more problems than they solve and would leave them turned off. If you have each document you write in a folder of its own the directories are clean enough, I think.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch BibTeX with eg `bibtex document`, the program will not look to `document.tex` but search for `document.aux` and read in it:

1. the list of `.bib` files
2. the `.bst`style to use
3. your ``\cite```s.

Hence the `.aux` files is mandatory. 
Beside this it produces the expected `document.bbl`and only one additional "intermediate" file: the BibTeX log file `document.blg`.

off topic for `Texpad`, but could be useful for other people: 
`MiKTeX` pdftex has an option `--aux-directory` (used with e;g. `--aux-directory=.\build`), where the intermediate files, including the `.aux` file are stored in the `build` folder, which is more generic.
However, the regular BibTeX run is no longer possible : one has to use a batch (or shell) script to either copy the `.aux` file to the working directory or copy the `.bib` files to the  `build` directory. Here is the `bibtex-build` batch file I use under Windows (to be converted by somebody else to Apple script for Mac OS X users)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
copy *.bib build
cd build
for %%f in (*.aux) do (
bibtex %%~nf
)
echo error level is %ERRORLEVEL% 
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    goto fin
) ELSE (
    pause
)
:fin
cd ..
```

The loop over `*.aux` could seem superfluous, but is needed if one use the `multibib` package or similar one which produces several `.aux` for a single document.