# Export table of contents (TOC) to RTF format

Tags: table-of-contents, export, latex2rtf

**Background**

I am wondering if it is possible to export table of contents in a .toc file to RTF format using LaTeX?

**Minimal Working Example**

What I could find is something close, but the below solution only produces a .txt file.

See further: [How can I export the Table of Contents to Text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346636/how-can-i-export-the-table-of-contents-to-text)

Comment: You can make a LaTeX file containing only the ToC like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346640/ and then run pandoc on that file to convert to RTF (or docx, or odt, or a multitude of other formats).

Comment: @Marijn Could you elaborate what you mean with pandoc?

Comment: Pandoc is a document converter tool. See [questions on TeX.SE tagged pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandoc?tab=Frequent) and the [Pandoc website](https://pandoc.org/) for more information.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, I understand how it works. But for some reason, despite using `\tableofcontents` command - no .toc file get generated. What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: To be clear: the procedure suggested in my first comment is first to compile your normal document to generate the `.toc` file, and then to write the small helper file as described in the linked answer to get only the table of contents in the output and not the rest of the document. Pandoc should be run on the second file, not on the first (the first file should be compiled with pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex, or any other latex).

Comment: Now if the first compilation does not generate a `.toc` file, then maybe you are compiling in a way that deletes auxiliary files after a succesful compilation. Some editors do this, but also compile tools such as latexmk or arara of texify etc. can be configured to delete files like `.toc` and `.bbl` etc. In that case you should configure the editor or tool differently, or use a simpler way of compiling (for example directly from the terminal/command prompt).

Comment: @Marijn That solved it, for some reason the app Texpad on Mac did not generate a `.toc` file and there were no settings to disable this. After that I had to fix my path to `pdflatex` in Terminal by adding `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin` to `bash_profile` and after that everything worked.

Comment: Related for Texpad (the question itself contains the related information, the answer is not relevant here): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437753/generate-bbl-file-and-no-other-intermediate-files

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for going above and beyond, so everything seems connected to the option "intermediate files" :-)